# Replace several if else statements in R with built-in functions while creating new column in data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a data frame containing long and specific names of gas stations (~Name). My goal is to create new column which will categorize those long names into few main brands based on the keywords occurring in the name (~Brand). I know that one way is to use several if else statements, but with large base of keywords, code will get really messy. So is there a way to achieve that with some functions from tidyverse packages or any other way omitting if else statements?

```
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(~Name,
             "POLSKI KONCERN NAFTOWY ORLEN SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA (STACJA NR 538)",
             "BP EUROPA SE SPÓŁKA EUROPEJSKA ODDZIAŁ W POLSCE",
             "LOTOS PALIWA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ",
             "STACJA PALIW VIP",
             "POLSKI KONCERN NAFTOWY ORLEN SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA (STACJA NR 125)",
             "POLSKI KONCERN NAFTOWY ORLEN SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA (STACJA NR 168)",
             "STACJA PALIW E. KOKOSZKO, BOLESŁAWIEC",
             "SHELL POLSKA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ (STACJA NR 5023)",
             "LOTOS PALIWA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ (NR 201)",
             "TESCO POLSKA SP. Z O.O.")

main_gas_stations <- c("ORLEN", "BP", "LOTOS", "SHELL")

df_final <- tribble(~Name,~Brand,
                    "POLSKI KONCERN NAFTOWY ORLEN SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA (STACJA NR 538)","ORLEN",
                    "BP EUROPA SE SPÓŁKA EUROPEJSKA ODDZIAŁ W POLSCE","BP",
                    "LOTOS PALIWA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ","LOTOS",
                    "STACJA PALIW VIP",NA,
                    "POLSKI KONCERN NAFTOWY ORLEN SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA (STACJA NR 125)","ORLEN",
                    "POLSKI KONCERN NAFTOWY ORLEN SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA (STACJA NR 168)","ORLEN",
                    "STACJA PALIW E. KOKOSZKO, BOLESŁAWIEC",NA,
                    "SHELL POLSKA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ (STACJA NR 5023)","SHELL",
                    "LOTOS PALIWA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ (NR 201)","LOTOS",
                    "TESCO POLSKA SP. Z O.O.",NA)
```

Comment: try `library(stringr);df %>% mutate(Brand = str_extract(Name, paste(main_gas_stations, collapse="|")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `paste` the 'main_gas_stations' with `|` (`OR`) and extract the word with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(Brand = str_extract(Name, paste(main_gas_stations, collapse="|")))
```